# Функция в canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

День добрый! Подскажите как сделать функционал в canvas,чтобы  по клику мыши по квадрату, он удалялся с экрана (с массива). В данном примере у меня удаляется весь массив, направьте на путь истинный)!

```js
function animate() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function Square(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = Math.random() * 620;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    this.g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    this.b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);

    this.rgba = "rgba(" + this.r + "," + this.g + "," + this.b + ",1)";

    this.draw = function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = this.rgba;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
      this.update();
    }

    this.update = function() {
      this.y += Math.random() * 2;
    }
  }

  var squares = [];

  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth);
    for (i = 0; i < squares.length; i++)
      squares[i].draw();
    update();
  }

  function update() {
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      squares[i].update();
    }
  }

  setInterval(function() {

    squares.push(new Square(0, 0, 20, 20))
  }, 1000);

  setInterval(draw, 20);
  var isCursorInSquares = function(x, y, squares) {
    return x > squares.x && x < squares.x + squares.w &&
      y > squares.y && y < squares.y + squares.h;
  }

  canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;

    for (i in squares)
      if (isCursorInSquares(x, y, squares[i]))
        delete squares[i]
  }
}

document.body.onload = animate;
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Обрабатываешь события клика по canvas, получаешь координаты мышки, по ним определяешь попал ли ты в нужный квадрат или нет

Comment: дай развернутый вопрос, выложи код, без кода трудно понять...  Чего тебе надобно "СТАРЧЕ"....?

Comment: меня интересует само событие по удалению квадрата, в который я попал мышкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все кубики пропадают, потому что у вас в коде ошибка и скрипт перестаёт работать.
Надо ваш кусок кода

```
for (i in squares)
  if (isCursorInSquares(x, y, squares[i]))
    delete squares[i]
```

заменить на

```
for(var i = squares.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if(isCursorInSquares(x, y, squares[i])) squares.splice(i, 1);
}
```

1. Элементы массива так не удаляют.
2. Удалять следует с конца массива, а не сначала, что бы не выйти за пределы массива при индексации.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё работает.

Comment: delete не нужен, splice  и так удаляет из массива

Comment: Точно, не нужен, забыл его удалить, подправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas - чёрный ящик. Все что нарисовано не функционально, вы можете только перерисовать. Вместо Canvas используйте SVG. Там вы сможете сделать с графическими элементами то же, что и с DOM элементами - навешивать события, вставлять, удалять и прочее.

Comment: Задание нужно сделать именно в canvas.